# VS build fails complaining "unable to locate repository containing directory,,,"

Tags: c#, git, quartz.net-3.0

I have recently downloaded the latest Quartz.NET (3.0.7) which is maintained using git (I guess). I downloaded the zip file and I intend to use it in a small task. I don't want to commit it back and I don't need it to be pointed to the git repository.

However, when I tried to compile the solution, it complains `unable to locate repository containing directory...` for every project in the solution from the task Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets. So my guess is the build process is trying to call some git-related tasks? But I can't find anything related to git in the source files/configuration. So how can I remove these git-related tasks from the solution/project configuration?

Answer (score 7):

The git-related tasks are caused by a reference to Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub in the src\Directory.Build.props file.

Instead of trying to remove them, the simplest way to get the build to stop complaining would be to initialize a new git repo for the solution, by running

```
git init
```

from a command prompt in the solution directory.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue as the original poster did. Git init did clear that issue! Then I had a build error related to the need for an AssemblyInfo.cs file in the root src directory. I created a dummy one without any settings and that got the solution building. Thanks Dan Z!